# I cannot connect to OpenSSH server running on Ubuntu server from Git bash running Windows, through Cyberoam firewall in network

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, firewall, linux-networking, client-server

**Situation:** I am trying to connect from `OpenSSH` client inbuilt with `Git Bash` running on Windows 7 professional x64 to `OpenSSH` server that runs on Ubuntu Server LTS 14 x64. Both of which are over the same local network, that is monitored by `Cyberoam`.

Also I need to mention that the server installation is fresh and for now I am the only one who is trying to connect to the system.

**Problems:**

- Out of 100 tries to connect from client, hardly 5 attempts are successful, and the rest are rejected by server, i.e. I cannot connect to the server from client, in normal process.
- Sometime right after successful long in, I get disconnected from server, I do not think it is the problem with time out.

**Ideal solution:** I should be able to connect to from client to server for each single attempt. Server should not refuse the connection.

**More details:**

- If I run run the SSH command from client in debug mode, I get:

`$ ssh -vvv 192.168.0.120
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.120 [192.168.0.120] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.120 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.120 port 22: Bad file number`
This is not the only message I get, sometimes at the end of the list, there is an error from the server.

- SSH is running over the default port, 22.
- If I use [PortQry.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148) to test the port and IP accessibility, I get no issue.

`$ portqry -n 192.168.0.120 -e 22
 Querying target system called:
 192.168.0.120
 Attempting to resolve IP address to a name...
 Failed to resolve IP address to name
 querying...
 TCP port 22 (ssh service): LISTENING`

- As mentioned the connection is gone though a a phycal firewall called `Cyberoam`, that has been newly reconfigured and all the problems started since then.
- I have checked `/var/log/auth.log`, but there is no entry for remote access via SSH from client machine.
- I have already set the keys on client and server, and I can log in with out password.
- I can ssh to server itself with no issues.

Comment: *As mentioned the connection is gone though a a phycal firewall called Cyberoam, that has been newly reconfigured and all the problems started since then.* that sounds like you already isolated the problem and know where to start looking further. Check the firewall config.

Comment: @HBruijn: The issue is that, the firewall is under the administration of IT technician and he says that he has not done anything to cause this, I do not have access to that part, or I can solidly state that THIS IS THE PROBLEM

Answer (score 0):

Something like this where the problem is intermittent, and (by your own description) caused by a firewall, I would immediately look at IPS. Ask your network admin to disable the Intrusion Prevention Service for 22/tcp to 192.168.0.120.

Comment: Intrusion Prevention Service is disabled on the inter connection network